# Why is murder considered a major sin when taking and giving life is only in the hands of Allah?

Tags: sharia, sin

Murder is considered as a Major Sin in Islam, because taking and giving life is only in the hands of Allah.  (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Anything that happens has to be according to the will of Allah.  Likewise, whatever happens to a person is written by Allah in his fate (Again, please correct me if I am wrong.)

If that is so, that means the murder of the person was already written by Allah in his fate and had Allah's acceptance.  Then why it is considered major sin?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, it is a major sin because "killing an innocent is the same as killing every human beings". This is the philosophy of 'murdering' in Islam. This is entirely relative to fate - I will come back to this later on.

***Fate is not a movie scenario.***

Think of fate as a network or a web. There are tens, hundreds, thousands and millions of different posibilities available.

The only known fact of fate is that we will all return to him / we will die. But, which road we take to the end of the line is entirely up to us. **But of course Allah knows which path we will take.** - that is a different matter.

Scenario: I can choose to jump out my window right now and die. Now Allah knows what I will do but it is not forced upon us. Does that make sense? If it was forced - if everything was written and we had no freedom of choice - there would be no judgement; as a result no purpose for humans.

Even simpler: I'm currently thirsty, Allah knows when I will drink water but I still yet to decide.

**Now back to your question.**

> If that is so, that means the murder of the person was already written by Allah in his fate and had Allah's acceptance. Then why it is considered major sin?

When you kill someone, **you** actually **interfere with their fate**. Not only their fate but the entire fate running of from that person - Example: the persons kids, grandkids, and the line goes on until the end of time.

Back to what I wrote at the top - "killing an innocent is the same as killing every human beings"

If we were to travel back in time and killed the first born human - Adam, there would be no humans.

[Allah knows best]

Answer (score 0):

This actually boils down to "What is fate and free will?" question. Something being "written" in advance and destined is relative to us, this world: the time. However, Allah is beyond the time: His will and knowledge is absolute and is not encompassed by the time; His knowledge has no beginning or an end. From that point of view, there is no

```
Allah's will ---sometime later---> murder
```

kind of flow of events. Allah knows a person is going to kill someone with his absolute knowledge without the limitation of the time. That's His knowing of the event is not before, during or after the fact.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as far as I can tell, it just replaces one incomprehensible claim (the conflict between free will and qadr) with another (god acting without time - I can't imagine what that means).

Comment: @G.Bach, _time is a creature created by the God, and it can not encompass God._ That's the basics of Islamic faith (i.e., Allah is the ultimate creator of everything and nothing can encompass Him). If we can't agree on that, there is no point in discussing anything.

Comment: I understand what the theology says; my criticism is that this answer fails to make sense of it.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I know it is a difficult matter to understand (especially for non-believers). However, I don't know any simpler way of explaining it.

Comment: You don't have to be convinced of a statement to understand it, and you don't have to understand it to be convinced of it. If you explain it in a reasonable way, then that makes for a good answer; as is, what you wrote does not explain it.

Comment: Well, the whole _logic_ is based on the _God acting without time_ concept. As I said in the first comment, if one can not comprehend that, there is no way for her to understand the _logic_ in this answer.

Comment: "Well, the whole logic is based on the God acting without time concept." You still haven't explained what "acting without time" is supposed to mean. I know what each of those words means, but they make no sense together - it's irrelevant that you say "God" in the same sentence. The question is about making sense of the theology; you can't do that by replacing one incomprehensible statement with another. This is getting too long though, so if you'd like to talk about this, feel free to invite me to a chatroom.

Comment: That means Allah's knowledge of a person's action (or fate) do not happen before, during or after the fact.

Comment: What does it mean to know something if there is no time in which you could do any recalling or pondering? What does it mean to say "he knows outside of time what she will do" when time in the form of "will do" already snuck in?

Comment: I think you need to ask/start a separate question for that.

Answer (score -2):

> whatever happens to a person is written by Allah in his fate (Again, please correct me if I am wrong.)
>
> If that is so, that means the murder of the person was already written by Allah in his fate and had Allah's acceptance.  Then why it is considered major sin?

DONT BELIVE FATE, why? because by believing fate you will ignore heaven and hell.
FOR EXAMPLE,when you playing chess you will anticipate your opponent next move and you will do something about it.
ALLAH knows what we will gonna do Allah shows the true path to us but those who dont listen to Allah, will go from wrong path and they will commit sins.

and thats all.

Fate is something we build it. we can think and decide for ourself.
and thats prove it.

Comment: Not believing in qadr is disbelief.

Comment: one simply cannot deny fate.